# In PowerBI (Desktop), how to group timestamp per day (or week or month)?

Tags: timestamp, powerbi

On PowerBI (Desktop), I am working with a file containing multiple rows and 2 columns.

> Timestamp         | Value
>
> 29/08/2018 04:45  | 105
>
> 29/08/2018 05:00  | 111
>
> 29/08/2018 05:15  | 112
>
> 29/08/2018 05:30  | 111
>
> 29/08/2018 05:45  | 113
>
> 29/08/2018 06:00  | 115
>
> 29/08/2018 06:15  | 111
>
> 29/08/2018 06:30  | 104

I want to build a new table by grouping all the rows related to the same day and compute the average of the related values.

I am quite new on PowerBI and didn't manage to find how to do this.

I tried to group the rows by creating a new column like this:

```
Day = FORMAT([Timestamp],"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

but the content of this new column remains the same of Timestamp.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Did you try to set the type of your first column to a Date/Timefrom the Query Editor? It should break down the date components and allow you to group by day, month, etc.

Comment: I did but I get the following error: "We can't automatically convert the column to Date/Time type." without other details...

Answer (score 1):

For this case we need to follow two procedure

1) first create new column

```
Column = FORMAT(IF(WEEKDAY('DailyActiveUsers'[startDate].[Date],2)=1,'DailyActiveUsers'[startDate].[Date],DATEADD('DailyActiveUsers'[startDate].[Date],-WEEKDAY('DailyActiveUsers'[startDate].[Date],2)+1,DAY)),"MM/DD/YYYY")
```

2) then we need to create measure

```
Measure = SUM(DailyActiveUsers[owner])
```

Finally we will get 8 days grouped data as starting date and count something like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to split your `Timestamp` column in the Query Editor into a date column and a time column before trying to do anything else.

**Home > Split Column by Delimiter > Split by a Space**